# Anaconda after update: Command propmpt responding very slowly and IPython not loading

Tags: python, anaconda

I ran the `conda update --all` command, but unfortunately something went wrong with the update process and windows crashed. Now if I try to redo the update the terminal is responding very slowly, to the point where installing the update is impossible. Even worse I ran `conda update ipython`, which also executed very slowly and now the ipython console no longer works reporting: `ImportError: No module named 'IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp'`.

I tried to update anaconda as I recived the error: `line magic function %pyomo not found`, when executing one of the basic examples using pyomo.

What should be done to restore anaconda? I am using the Spyder IDE.

Comment: reinstall conda I guess

Comment: @Aiven Hmm... even the uninstaller gets stuck. Is it ok to just remove everything in the folder and reinstall?

Comment: I don't have much experience with windows but I guess that conda might have some dependencies outside its root folder, better to check conda docs for help with uninstallation